# Where would the best place to drill a hole to put an electrical panal to the inside of a 20' sea container?

Tags: wiring

I want to bring teck cord into my sea container (*conex or shipping container*).

Where would be the best place?

Comment: The top. (Why? because with the amount of info you've given us, that's as good a random guess as any other.)

Comment: Also, for those of us who don't know, what's "teck cord"?

Comment: I have never used it but have gathered that teck cable is very popular in Canada, and versatile stuff.  It's pretty close to PVC coated MC armored cable used in the US, you see it used a lot parking garages, but there's an additional jacket inside teck cable.

Comment: I would think the best place would be where you want the panel to be  located.

Answer (score 2):

If it is supported in a manner that makes it accessible, through the floor.

1. Least chance of leaks.
2. Depending on your particular container's construction details, only
   part that might be wood (if you miss the cross members) rather than
   steel, so easier to drill.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you've decided on a spot for the elctrical panel.  I'd enter the container through the wall, either directly behind the panel or just below the panel.

You could use an LB conduit body

[image: LB condulet]

With an outdoor rated connector on the end of the teck cable, you can connect right to the conduit body.

You might want to make a "J" at the bottom of the cable so the LB sits with the opening down.  That way you have a drip loop.

Depending on the size of the wires, you might want to oversize the LB to get a little extra room in there to bend the wires.  There are also special LBs made with more bend radius, look for either a "service entrance LB" or a "mogul LB."  You'd just use a reducing bushing between the teck connector and the LB.

You could place it so you come through the wall right into the back of the panel, or you could come into a junction box just below the panel.  The J-box would help if there's every any seepage around the opening, the water will leak into out of the j-box and drip on the floor, but at least it won't make a mess in the panel.

Comment: This is an excellent answer for the "how" question, but that's not what the OP asked...

Comment: @freeman - true; editing

Comment: They'd need a MC(Teck)-to-nipple "from-to" transition fitting instead of a normal Teck box connector